# Adding gulp created files to visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp

When i run a gulp task runner it does some tasks of bundling, minifying, etc of the file put it into our webroot folder.

My problem is the gulp created files and folders are not added to my project.

Can anybody help me to add those files to the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the show hidden files and then right click on them to add them, but... **I would advise against this**.

Adding files to the solution that are built for you means that if you ever delete those and then build there's a possibility that you'll get build errors because it can't find the files, which is a catch-22.  It will make CI very frustrating.  So I'd avoid it if you can and instead rely on conventions for where the files should be.

In addition, I'd advise against adding the compiled files to source control and would instead rely on a fresh build whenever you need them.

Comment: I am not trying to add the file that is build, i am trying to add the files that are bundled by gulp. I wanted gulp bundled files to be added to my project files.

Comment: You're adding the input files or the output files?